# Process builder hangs while running Linux command occasionally

Tags: java, multithreading

We are executing script and Linux command using process builder. Below is a rough example of the way we are using process builder.

```
class Example {

class Stopper extends TimerTask {
  Thread t ;
   Stopper( Thread t ){
    this.t = t;
  }
   public void run (){
    t.interrupt();  
  }
}

String command= <some command or script>;
String workingDirectory = <working directory>;
ProcessBuilder processbuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
processbuilder.setWorkingDirectory(workingDirectory);
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);


Timer timer = new Timer(true);
Stopper stop = new Stopper(Thread.currentThread());
timer.schedule(stop , 5); // 5 millisec

Process process = processBuilder.start();
// code to call the thread to read the output stream.
process.waitFor();

}
```

In spite of reading from the output stream, the process.waitFor() get interrupted by timer thread. When thread get interrupted below is snippet of error we see ( pasting only the relevant part )

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitFor(UNIXProcess.java:395)
```

The thread is interrupted intermittently and not always which means out by 1000 times same command run, it will timeout 10 times only. We tried increasing the timeout period but still it's not able to complete the command execution.

After searching for the issue, I see a bug in java which I feel is the issue but not sure. Any help on this is appreciated.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8169565

Comment: Why don't you just use the variant of Process.waitfor that has a timeout, rather than building one with chewing gum and baling wire?   To the real problem - difficult to say since you don't show the reading code.

Comment: To clarify, user16632363 is referring to [this waitFor method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).  Much simpler than creating a separate thread.

Comment: But what difference does it make if i use overloaded waitFor ....command execution like chmod 644 <file name> takes more than 5 sec to execute ?.

Comment: If you only need to execute a chmod, [use Java to do it](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#setPosixFilePermissions(java.nio.file.Path,java.util.Set)).  Instead of chmod filename 644, use `Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Path.of(filename), PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rw-r--r--"))`.

Comment: It is more likely that your issue is simply that your process writes large volumes to STDOUT or STDERR and that you are not reading from `process.getInputStream()` effectively.